# 64bit vs 32 bit OS in programming

Tags: java, database, windows, computer-science

I want to know if there is really a big difference when programming with a 32bit OS against 64bit OS. If there is what are the advantages (in programming) when using a 64bit OS against a 32bit OS.

I gave up on reformatting my computer to a 64bit OS.

Additional thought: I am planning on learning 2-3 different programming language at the same time, besides java(what i am using right now) what other programming language i could simultaneously learn with? I have basic experience with java, c++ and visual basic. I am planning on learning web designs first then focused on security (thing). Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One question at a time is better.

Comment: `I am planning on learning 2-3 different programming language at the same time` - sorry, but you will fail. `reformatting my computer to a 64bit OS` --- what? That doesnt make much sense.

Comment: When develop internetworking apps, need for example Eclipse, Microsoft Visual Studio, two big (in term of RAM) developed apps ... 8GB RAM is very nice. BUT: poor computer better help catch performance problems by customer ;)

Comment: 64bit has sense when computer have big phisical memory. If has no more 4GB then 32 bit is better

Comment: Flagged as primarily opinion based, though this is also too broad.

Comment: I have a windows 7 32 bit OS, and I have been trying to reformat it to a @specializt 64 bit OS, and I've been failing pretty hard on doing it since every time I change the boot sequence and try to save the changes, nothing seems to happen does making me unable to do the reformatting. That is why I am asking if there are big difference in programming when using a 32bit OS against a 64 bit OS.

Comment: also : 64bit has quite a few advantages - modern Kernels can pack memory units together hence speed up retrieval and if the developer uses 64bit data types less of them are needed .... all in all its better in most ways.

Comment: @JacekCz thats a good point. and thanks for answering

Comment: @specializt thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

64 bits capability amounts to essentially two things:

- you can reach a much wider address space (32 bits is limited to 2GBytes - which is already huge),
- you can perform arithmetic on larger integers (no change for floats).

From the point of view of the programming languages, syntax and semantics, this has no serious impact and you shouldn't worry.

Comment: 32b is limited to 3.4GB, 2GB is windows limit for process IMHO

Comment: thanks for the awesome reply, atleast now im not that eager to have a 64 bit OS.

Comment: @JacekCz: and 2^32 addresses 4GB (Gibibytes). I didn't want to clutter my answer with technicalities.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged `Java` so to answer the 32/64 bit OS question:

No, there is no difference in how you will write pure java code. Java is platform independent. It compiles into bytecode, which is interpreted by the JVM (the JVM is specific to your OS).

If you start to use native interfaces such as JNI, then you will have to concern yourself with the difference between 32 and 64 bit binaries, but that is another story.

Comment: thanks for answering, atleast now im not that eager to have a 64 bit OS. If only i could upvote your answers. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Java being more loose coupled to OS than MS framework was very big benefit in time of upgrade production server 32b->64b, Java world was ready in 30min, rest in one night. But this sentence has nothing to do to programmers work. Simply Java is highly portable in this context too